A theorem to describe of all connections on a given vector bundle.
In the answer to this question Any connection in the trivial line bundle is given by the exterior derivative $d: C^\infty(M) \to \Omega^1(M)$
Matsmir gave me two propositions that help to understand how one can describe all connections on a given vector bundle.
Proposition 1. Let $E$ be a smooth vector bundle, and let $\nabla^1, \nabla^2: \mathfrak X(M) \times \Gamma(E) \rightarrow \Gamma(E)$ be connections. Then their difference $D(X,Y) = \nabla^1_X Y - \nabla^2_X Y$ is a $C^\infty$-bilinear mapping $\mathfrak X(M) \times \Gamma(E) \rightarrow \Gamma(E)$. That is $D(fX,Y) = fD(X,Y) = D(X,fY)$ for any $f \in C^\infty(M)$. Conversely, if $\nabla$ is a connection and $D$ is a $C^\infty$-bilinear mapping $D:\mathfrak X(M) \times \Gamma(E) \rightarrow \Gamma(E)$, then $\nabla + D$ is a connection.
Proposition 2. Let $E,F,G$ be vector bundles over $M$ and let $D:\Gamma(E)\times \Gamma(F) \rightarrow \Gamma(G)$ be a $C^\infty$-bilinear mapping. Then $D$ is canonically induced by a section of the vector bundle $E^* \otimes F^* \otimes G$. In more simple words, $D$ comes from a smooth family of bilinear mappings $D_x:E_x \times F_x \rightarrow G_x$, $x \in M$ by virtue of the formula $D(X,Y)(x) = D_x(X(x), Y(x))$.
That is to describe all connections one can construct a single connection and then add all possible ''difference tensors''.
I have already proven the first proposition, but no luck witht the second one. Could you help me prove proposition 2 or send me to a resource with the proof? Furthermore I don't see very clearly how the combination of these two propositions implies all connections  are of the form $\nabla +D$

Maybe show us how far you can get and where you get stuck?

@Deane I don't even understand how to translate  the words in the proposition to equations or interpret what I have to do.  I mean "is canonically induced by","comes from" .

Perhaps you could include the proof to the first proposition?
